# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Productview_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.7

In Magento admin, when trying to Add a New Role I am getting this error:

Login to admin
Go to System->Permmissions->Roles->Add New Role

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Productview_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 546

Please help. I tried to replace Adminhtml folder with fresh extraction folder but could not help

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

adding

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        if ($helperClass != "Mage_Productview_Helper_Data" )//add THIS line 
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

to **/app/Mage.php** (line 547)

And also, comment out:

```
if ( is_null($represent2Darray) ) {
    //$result[$resourceName]['name']  = Mage::helper($module)->__((string)$resource->title);
    $result[$resourceName]['level'] = $level;
}
```

in **/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php** (line 160)

Hope this helps.